# Pass reference variable by-ref or by-val?

Tags: .net, pass-by-reference

This may seem like a dumb question, or even subjective, but I'm not sure what's the right way to do this.

I have a method that receives a class and alters it (in particular, it adds a new column to a 
DataTable). I understand that, working with reference types, I can pass it by-value or by-reference, the behavior won't change in this case.

In one hand, I don't like adding more indirection than needed. If by-val works, I like to use it.

In the other hand, by-ref makes my intention clearer (Although the method's name should be enough for this).

Which should I use, and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the behaviour *does* change when a reference type parameter is "by reference". That means changes to the *parameter itself* will be seen by the caller.

If you make a parameter "by reference" when you don't want that, you're making your code *less* clear rather than *more* clear. It suggests that you *will* change the parameter, rather than just modifying the object that the parameter refers to. That will also restrict how your method can be called, as the argument would have to be an l-value. Not a good idea.

See my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

Comment: Anyway, I was thinking in VB so, AFAIK there's no functional difference *in this case* (as long as I'm not assigning anything to the parameter). It's still a good point, as my code could be called from C# in the future...

Comment: @Jaime: I doubt that you can pass the result of another method call to a method as an argument for a ByRef parameter. I hope not, anyway. I know you can pass properties by reference in VB, but I *hope* it doesn't go further than that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I fear you are wrong. I just checked it to be sure, and it's allowed even with Option Strict On, in vs2005 and 2010.

Comment: @Jaime: Ick. That's revolting. I can't imagine why that's allowed, unless it's for purely historical reasons. Anyway, don't do it :)

Comment: Backwards compatibility, I guess. It really puzzles me the "backwards compatibility" of VB.Net. "We'll change the language in a myriad breaking ways 'cause, you know, vb6 suckz, but we will maintain *this* and *this* just to mock the poor coderz, mwahaha." I really don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass by reference *unless you want to replace the passed instance entirely*. When you pass an instance of a reference type, the called method will always be able to interact with it (altering property values, calling methods and so on). The only thing the called method cannot do, is to replace the passed instance with an etirely new instance in a way that will be reflected in the calling code.

Comment: As I stated, I already understood the difference between by-ref and by-val. But thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps best explained with an example:

```
    //pass by val because you are not changing the reference
    public void FillCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        customer.Firstname = "Joe";
        customer.Surname = "Bloggs";
    }

    //pass by ref because you are changing the reference
    public void FillCustomer(ref Customer customer)
    {
        customer = new Customer
        {
            customer.Firstname = "Joe";
            customer.Surname = "Bloggs";
        };
    }
```